# Pesquisa Usando Combo box

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Estou com um `ComboBox` que quando eu seleciono o status Ativo ou Inativo ele esvazia meu `DataGrid`
O que eu gostaria que ele fizesse fosse selecionar uma das duas Opções e trazer todos os registros com o Status ativo, por um exemplo

codigo que estou usando :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strSelect = "SELECT * FROM Produto WHERE status LIKE (@status)";
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=ProdPacote; Uid=root; pwd=1234;"))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSelect, conn);
            //Passagem por parâmetros.
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "status");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["status"];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom resolvi consegui trazer dados do `DataGrid` da seguinte forma troquei o `comboBox1.SelectedValue` por `comboBox1.text`, agora ele traz somente os registros com o status Ativo ou Inativo

segue codigo abaixo:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strSelect = "SELECT * FROM Produto WHERE status LIKE (@status)";
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=ProdPacote; Uid=root; pwd=1234;"))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSelect, conn);
            //Passagem por parâmetros.
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", comboBox1.Text + "%");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "status");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["status"];
        }
    }
```